# ArcPy Get Value of Field for Selected Record

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, python-script-tool

I am building a script to populate a field in one feature class based on a field in another feature class.  First I have a leases layer which is all small polygons.  Then I have an index grid layer which is large polygons.  I want to know which leases exist within which index grid polygon.  The index grid layer has an "Id" field, and I want the Id value from the index grid that each lease exists within to be written to a new column in the leases layer.

For example, index grid polygon with an 'Id' of '7' contains leases '14' '6' and '12'.  The final result should be a column where lease 14, 6, and 12 all have a value of '7' in the new column.

Here is what I have so far:

```
import arcpy, sys

grid = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
leases = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
new_field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

if arcpy.ListFields(leases, new_field):
    sys.exit(arcpy.AddError("Error:Field Already exists"))

arcpy.AddField_management(leases, new_field, 'SHORT', '', '', '')

grid_lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(grid, 'grid_lyr')
leases_lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(leases, 'leases_lyr')

fields = ['file',new_field]
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(leases_lyr,fields) as cur:
    for row in cur:

        leases = row[0]
        where = '"file" = \'{}\''.format(leases)
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(leases_lyr, 'NEW_SELECTION', where)

        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(grid_lyr, 'CONTAINS', leases_lyr)
        map_no =  #I think this is all that is missing

        row[1] = map_no
        cur.updateRow(row)
```

The value 'map_no' represents the index grid Id which the lease belongs to.

As I have a comment in my code, I think there is only one line that is missing...in the original script which this is derived from, this line uses the arcpy.GetCount_management, but obviously it needs to be something different.  It just needs to be some kind of get value function, but I simply cannot figure it out.

I derived this work so far from a script that counts the number of points in in a polygon, and then writes that value to a new column in the polygon layer.  I mention this because maybe there is a better solution.

Using ArcMap 10.1.

Comment: Most of select layer code should be able to be replaced with a single call to [Spatial Join](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm). No need to loop over each feature.

Comment: Thanks Paul - I didn't even realize there was a separate spatial join tool (Analysis toolbox).  I ran that and was able to achieve exactly what I wanted.  However, I would still be interested to see if anyone has something simple to add to my script to make it work.

Comment: I'd probably use a cursor on `grid_lyr` to access the id field value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the [Spatial Join (Analysis) Tool.](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm)

Use the index grid as the target feature and the leases as the join feature.
Enter the output Feature Class.
Select one to many relationship.
Join type - keep all.
Leave field mapping as is or remove unnecessary fields (it is only necessary to keep the '***index grid id***' field **as this will be the final result**).
Lastly, select the join operator 'CONTAINS'.

The link above also shows how to access this tool using arcpy if desired.

Answer (score 4):

Going to assume that not all grids contain leases and that grids completely contain leases. No need to make the "in_memory" feature class if all grids will be used. If some leases overlap grids, you will only get the last grid id value.

```
import arcpy, sys

grid = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
leases = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
new_field = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)

if arcpy.ListFields(leases, new_field):
    sys.exit(arcpy.AddError("Error:Field Already exists"))

arcpy.AddField_management(leases, new_field, 'SHORT', '', '', '')

grid_lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(grid, 'grid_lyr')
leases_lyr = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(leases, 'leases_lyr')

fields = ['file',new_field]
arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(grid_lyr, "CONTAINS", leases_lyr)
arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(grid_lyr, "in_memory", "gridsWithLeases")
gridsWithLeases = r"in_memory/gridsWithLeases"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(gridsWithLeases, 'gridLease_lyr')
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor('gridLease_lyr', ['ID']) as gridCursor:
    for gridRow in gridCursor:
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(leases_lyr, "WITHIN", 'gridLease_lyr')
        with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(leases_lyr, fields) as leaseCursor:
            for leaseRow in leaseCursor:
                leaseRow[1] = gridRow[0]
                leaseCursor.updateRow(leaseRow)
```

Comment: Updated with corrections.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - there were, and still are, a few issues with this script.
I had to indent line 23 and below of your code (starting with arcpy.SelecyLayerByLocation_management) and I had to change the spelling of conversion on line 18.
I won't be able to do any more debugging for a while, but the error that is coming up now is `NameError: name 'gridsWithLeases' is not defined
`. I think this may have something to do with adding quotes around `gridsWithLeases` but I could be wrong. Either way there is still work to be done here.